# In R, using `unique()` with extra conditions to extract submatrices: easy solution without plyr

Tags: r, matrix, unique, submatrix

In R, let `M` be the matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    3
[3,]    2    4    5
[4,]    6    7    8
```

I would like to select the submatrix `m`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    3
[2,]    2    4    5
[3,]    6    7    8
```

using `unique` on `M[,1]`, specifying to keep the row with the maximal value in the second column`M`.
At the end, the algorithm should keep row `[2,]` from the set `\{[1,], [2,]\}`. Unfortunately `unique()` returns me a vector with actual values, and not row numbers, after elimination of duplicates.

Is there a way to get the asnwer without the package plyr?
Thanks a lot,
Avitus

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to avoid using `plyr`?

Comment: I am not a programmer, so I would like to learn step by step as much as possible :-). plyr is great, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
is.first.max <- function(x) seq_along(x) == which.max(x)

M[as.logical(ave(M[, 2], M[, 1], FUN = is.first.max)), ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    3
# [2,]    2    4    5
# [3,]    6    7    8
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `duplicated`.

```
m <- as.matrix(read.table(text="1    2    3
1    3    3
2    4    5
6    7    8"))
m <- m[order(m[,2], decreasing=TRUE), ]
m[!duplicated(m[,1]),]

#      V1 V2 V3
# [1,]  6  7  8
# [2,]  2  4  5
# [3,]  1  3  3
```

Comment: but this will not preserve the original row order.

Comment: If OP specifies that as a requirement, I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @flodel and Matthew Plourde: the row order is not a problem. Both answers are much appreciated; I was searching for a short but smart code to get the result. Many thanks! Avitus

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient:

```
M <- matrix(c(1,1,2,6,2,3,4,7,3,3,5,8),4)

t(sapply(unique(M[,1]),function(i) {temp <- M[M[,1]==i,,drop=FALSE]
                                    temp[which.max(temp[,2]),]                                  
         }))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    3
#[2,]    2    4    5
#[3,]    6    7    8
```

Comment: I never used `sapply` before :-). Thanks for your code. It is interesting the use of `t()` at the very end, though.